# RabbitMQ inequivalent arg 'x-max-length-bytes' Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I try to send some message in RabbitMQ with spring, but everytime on the first message I got an Exception of this type:

```
    com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: 
    #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - 
    inequivalent arg 'x-max-length-bytes' for queue
    'queue1' 
    in vhost 'f46b51d8-0750-4e7e-9288-3bdb3c5dac01': 
    received none but current is the value '1073741824' of type 'long', class
    id=50, method-id=10)    
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) 
    at 
 com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32)    
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366)    
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229)  
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117)  ... 68 moreCaused by:
```

I don't set x-max-length-bytes in my configuration

```
spring.rabbitmq.host= xxxxxx
spring.rabbitmq.port= 5671
spring.rabbitmq.username= xxxxxx
spring.rabbitmq.password= xxxxxx
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host= f46b51d8-0750-4e7e-9288-3bdb3c5dac01
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled= true
rabbimq.exchange.name= ex1
rabbimq.queue.name= queue1
rabbimq.routing.key= route1
```

the other messages are sent correctly but only the first message causes this exception

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It appears to me that `queue1` is expecting the arg `x-max-length-bytes`.

Answer (score 3):

`PRECONDITION_FAILED` means that you have a queue already declared, and you are trying to redeclare the same queue with different paramenters.

check the queue using the management UI or the command line:

```
rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

Comment: Yes tha't right...the queue exists and I want to use the queue that already exists...How can I say to Spring Boot that I want only to use the exchange and the queue and I don't want to redeclare them?